# Fetching Data using .getJSON and storing using Knockout.JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

My TweetModel is setup like this

```
function TweetModel(tweet) {
    var self = this;
        this.tweet = ko.observable(tweet);
}
```

[UPDATED]

Running into trouble binding the solution.  For some reason, after the TweetModel object is created, it is not being pushed to self.tweets.
I broke this up into steps...

```
.getJSON(someurl, function(data){
    $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            var tweetModel = new TweetModel();
            tweetModel.tweet = data.key[0];
            self.tweets.push(tweetModel);
            //all could be compressed into self.tweets.push(new TweetModel(val)); 
            //Object is being created but self.tweets returns an empty list when debugged
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what "Object is being returned as `Object {key: Array[1]}`" means, but did you try `$.each(data.key, function (i, val) {`?

Comment: OK, I'll add it as an answer then.

Comment: How is self.tweets declared/initialized?  Also, is anything being logged to the console?

Comment: `self.tweets = ko.observableArray();`

Comment: Everything sounds right, so I'm not sure what's going on.  Using `self.tweets.push` is the right way to add to the observable array and trigger the appropriate notifications.  One thing you need to be careful of with observable arrays is that when checking the length you need to use `self.tweets().length` - `self.tweets.length` will always be 0, from my experience.  The same with getting items  - e.g. `self.tweets()[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON(someurl, function (data) {
    $.each(data.key, function (i, val) {
        self.tweets.push(new TweetModel(val));
    }
}
```