# Knockout JS applying bindings to observableArray

Tags: knockout.js

```
function TweetModel(tweet) {
var self = this;
    this.tweet = ko.observable(tweet);
}
```

After the TweetModel object is created, it is not being pushed to self.tweets.

```
.getJSON(someurl, function(data){
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
        var tweetModel = new TweetModel();
        tweetModel.tweet = data.key[0];
        self.tweets.push(tweetModel);
        //all could be compressed into self.tweets.push(new TweetModel(val)); 
}}
```

The TweetModel object is being created but self.tweets returns an empty list when debugged.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you show viewmodel code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fetching Data using .getJSON and storing using Knockout.JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23529434/fetching-data-using-getjson-and-storing-using-knockout-js)

Answer (score 0):

First of all

```
this.tweet = ko.observable(tweet);
```

above line will make tweet as observable variable and not observable array, so make it

```
  this.tweet = ko.observableArray();
```

Try changing

```
function TweetModel() {
var self = this;
    this.tweet = ko.observable();
}

.getJSON(someurl, function(data){
$.each(data, function (i, val) {
        var tweetModel = new TweetModel();
        tweetModel.tweets.push(data.key[0]);
       //all could be compressed into self.tweets.push(new TweetModel(val)); 
}}
```